# Fix offset points to grid in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have points that are mostly on a 3d grid. The spacing is known in all cases (spacing = 0.2,0.2,0.25) but the start/end coordinates can be different in each case.

There are a few points that are slightly offset from the grid.

e.g. an offset point in the z direction
1,1,0.75; 1,1,1; **1,1,1.1**; 1,1,1.25; 1,1,1.5

I am struggling to find an efficient way to fix these offset point to their nearest 'correct' location. Specifically how to handle cases where it is the minimum or maximum coordinate that is offset from the grid

My approach...

```
duo = sortrows(duo,1);
a = diff(duo(:,1));
b = find(a>0.00001 & abs(a-0.2)>0.00001);
if mod(length(b),2) == 1
    display('Grid issue. Failing...');
    return;
end
for i=1:2:length(b)
    if abs(duo(b(i),1)-duo(b(i)+1,1)) < abs(duo(b(i+1),1)-duo(b(i+1)+1,1))
        for j=b(i)+1:b(i+1)
            duo(j,1) = duo(b(i),1);
        end
    else
        for j=b(i)+1:b(i+1)
            duo(j,1) = duo(b(i+1)+1,1);
        end
    end
end

duo = sortrows(duo,2);
a = diff(duo(:,2));
b = find(a>0.00001 & abs(a-0.2)>0.00001);
if mod(length(b),2) == 1
    display('Grid issue. Failing...');
    return;
end
for i=1:2:length(b)
    if abs(duo(b(i),2)-duo(b(i)+1,2)) < abs(duo(b(i+1),2)-duo(b(i+1)+1,2))
        for j=b(i)+1:b(i+1)
            duo(j,2) = duo(b(i),2);
        end
    else
        for j=b(i)+1:b(i+1)
            duo(j,2) = duo(b(i+1)+1,2);
        end
    end
end

duo = sortrows(duo,3);
a = diff(duo(:,3));
b = find(a>0.00001 & abs(a-0.25)>0.00001);
if mod(length(b),2) == 1
    display('Grid issue. Failing...');
    return;
end
for i=1:2:length(b)
    if abs(duo(b(i),3)-duo(b(i)+1,3)) < abs(duo(b(i+1),3)-duo(b(i+1)+1,3))
        for j=b(i)+1:b(i+1)
            duo(j,3) = duo(b(i),3);
        end
    else
        for j=b(i)+1:b(i+1)
            duo(j,3) = duo(b(i+1)+1,3);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: In your example, what *is* the correct location?  If you use some form of rounding (which would be my first guess), then you will end up with two points at (1,1,1).  Is that what you want?  If you are talking about the end-points (e.g. the first) being offset, again, what is the "correct" answer?  (Isn't it equally valid to move every other point to line up with the position of the first)?  If you can define more precisely what is correct, and what is wrong, then it will be easier to write your solution in code.  Please also remember this is not a code writing forum, so try it first yourself..

Comment: Yes, another 1,1,1 would be correct - maybe it was a bad example. I suppose you are right, it wouldn't be incorrect to move all the points to line up with the first. I have tried it myself, I'll edit the first post to add my code

Comment: In that case, you should consider how you can use round.  If the grid `spacing = [0.2,0.2,0.25]`, *and* you assume that the origin is a grid point, then it is simply `spacing.*round(point./spacing)`.  Obviously you this only deals with one point - you should alter it to deal with a list of points in the form of a matrix.  If you need the grid to be registered relative to some other point (i.e. the origin is not necessarily on the grid), then you need to define the problem more clearly, in which case you should be able to generate your own solution.

Comment: Having just seen your question edit, it looks like you cannot use the origin as your reference, but you must define the reference point somehow.  Once you have a reference point, then the solution I've suggested is easily altered to become `spacing.*round((point-reference)./spacing)+reference`